# Calling a sub procedure in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, stored-procedures

Just want to ask you  if I'm doing the right way calling sub procedure in vb.net I've already tested it and it is working. I just want to know if I need to change my coding way?

So here's my Sub procedure:

```
Sub loadStudDB()

 'To load student info from database and pass it through objecs from winform'

    Try
        con.Open()
        Dim studid As Integer = Val(Form1.studentidtxt.Text)
        Dim selectQ = "SELECT * FROM StudentInfoTBL WHERE StudentID=@studid"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(selectQ, con)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studid", studid)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If dr.HasRows Then
            dr.Read()

            studidtxt.Text = dr.Item("StudentID").ToString
            studname.Text = dr.Item("StudentName")
            agebox.Text = dr.Item("Age").ToString

            If dr.Item("Gender") = "Male" Then
                malebtn.Checked = True
            Else
                femalebtn.Checked = True
            End If

            dobtxt.Text = dr.Item("DOB")
            homeaddtxt.Text = dr.Item("Home Address")
            citytxt.Text = dr.Item("City").ToString
            telephonetxt.Text = dr.Item("Telephone")
            mobiletxt.Text = dr.Item("Mobile")
            emailtxt.Text = dr.Item("Email")

            dr.Close()
            con.Close()

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Then I'll call it from form load event:

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     'call procedure created'
        loadStudDB()
    End Sub
```

Comment: If you do not have any errors in your code, and it works as expected, then you've done it 'correctly.' If you are looking for advice on possible ways to make your code better, more efficient, easier to read, then try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You need an `End Sub` at the end of your sub procedure, but apart from that it looks good.

Comment: You may want to consider wrapping your SqlCommand declaration in a `using` block.   This will guarantee that the command gets disposed when your method ends.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wydd5hkd.aspx

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).